# Is "more" an adverb or an adjective in "There is nothing more you need to do."

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is "more" an adverb or an adjective in "There is nothing more you need to do." I feel it can be regarded as an adverb as it modifies "you need to do." However, it can also be regarded as an adjective that modifies the noun "nothing."

Comment: Presumably you mean '_or_ an adjective'?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typo, just fixed it

Comment: Technically, it modifies the word nothing, and is an adjective in this case.

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon, that seems backwards: *nothing* modifies *more*. I.E., "There is more to do," meaning a task is to be completed, and, "There is *nothing* more to do," where *nothing* negates *more*.

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon are you sure "more" isn't a noun here?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik, is "nothing" here an adverb or adjective?